# Postgres. Применяю GROUP BY, но могу получить поля не отмеченные в GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Сколько мне известно, при наличии `GROUP BY` в запросе, `SELECT` обязан содержать либо поля из `GROUP BY`, либо аггрегатные функции. Однако у меня есть рабочий контр-пример - и я не вполне могу понять, почему он работает.

Запрос:

```
SELECT
    "tour"."number",
    "tour"."name",
    COUNT ( "protocol" ) AS "Protocols processed",
    COUNT ( "place" ) AS "Protocols total" 
FROM
    "tour"
    CROSS JOIN "place"
    LEFT JOIN "protocol" ON "protocol"."tour_id" = "tour"."id" 
    AND "protocol"."place_id" = "place"."id" 
WHERE
    "place"."editor_id" = 1
GROUP BY
    "tour"."id" 
ORDER BY
    "tour"."number"
```

1. Таблицы `tour` и `place` не имеют связи по ключам - но каждый `place` логически соответствует каждому `tour`.
2. Таблица `protocol` имеет составной первичный ключ `tour_id, place_id` - вместе,  и два внешних ключа - `tour_id`, `place_id` - отдельно.
3. Поля `tour.number` и `tour.name` - формально не обязательно уникальные, но логически должны почти всегда и мои тестовые данные содержат только уникальные значения этих полей.

Схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть природа такого поведения? По всему, что я знаю - такого быть не должно и запрос должен свалиться с ошибкой - ведь поля `tour.number` и `tour.name`в GROUP BY не содержатся.

Возможно, postgres проводит самостоятельный анализ и сам понимает их допустимость к добавлению в `SELECT`? Возможно, такого быть не должно и я упускаю потенциальный баг? Если второе правда, почему я не получаю ошибку, хотя по всем правилам должен?

Comment: Вероятнее всего дело в том что группировка идет по поле  **id** которое по идее уникальное.  А значит одному значению поля **id** строго соответствует одна строка из таблицы. А именно только эти поля участвуют в SELECT. Т.е. тут изначально нет никакой неоднозначности.

Comment: @newman иначе говоря, учебные материалы и статьи очень неполно описывают поведение СУБД, а сама СУБД умеет делать довольно умные вещи и анализировать все такие ситуации на однозначность? 

Интересно тогда узнать, будет ли это работать, если я в SELECT добавлю поле из другой таблицы, полученное с помощью JOIN, однако при этом все поля, участвующие в конструкции ON - то есть связывающие две таблицы, будут UNIQUE - в такой сиутации тоже нет никакой неоднозначности, но, с другой стороны, также всё куда более косвенно.

Comment: Не уверен, что такие зависимости анализатор запроса сможет просчитать. Все же проверка на primary key самая простая и очевидная вещь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему ошибка не выдается из-за того что группировка делается по полю **id**, которое является первичным ключом, а в выборке без использования аггрегирующих функций используются поля их этой таблицы. Т.е. есть четкое соотвествие какое именно поле должно попасть в выборку.

Попробовал на имеющейся у меня базе. Запрос вида

```
SELECT id, name, profile_id FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Выполняется без ошибок.

А вот запрос

```
SELECT id, name, profile_id FROM table GROUP BY profile_id
```

Уже выдает ошибку *ОШИБКА: колонка "table.id" должна фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции*

P.S.:
Этот момент описан в документации:
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/queries-table-expressions#queries-group

> Если бы в таблице products по столбцу product_id был создан первичный ключ, тогда в данном примере было бы достаточно сгруппировать строки по product_id, так как название и цена продукта функционально зависят от кода продукта и можно однозначно определить, какое название и цену возвращать для каждой группы по ID.

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо!

Comment: Я также проверил, попробовав поменять в своём запросе `GROUP BY "tour.id"` на `GROUP BY "tour.number"` - перед этив сделав `"tour.name"` UNIQUE. Тоже не запустилось. Очень обидно, что так происходит - уникальное поле чисто технически ничуть не меньше можно считать эквивалентном первичного ключа, да и функциональная зависимость присутствует...

Comment: О примере с JOIN и говорить не стоит - такого анализа тоже не происходит, хотя мог быть очень полезен в каких-нибудь хитрых и не очень хитрых ситуациях. Возможно, есть уже неизвестные мне технические ограничения.